# Explaining Child Elements in the Flat File Schema Wizard

Tags: visual-studio-2015, xsd, biztalk, wizard, flat-file

Ok so i was reading about the flat file schema wizard and was trying to figure out what the different choices of child elements do when you choose them for the different values in the wizard. And every time i use the wizard i get unsure to what the different choices do.

I think Microsoft only repeats what the two-word-name of the different choices already tells the user.

So could Someone do a better job explaining what the different choices mean:

- Field Element
- Field Attribute
- Record
- Repeating Record

For instance, one thing i'm always looking for is what choice refers to Column header name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a brief description:

**Field Element:** A value that you want to be in an XML tag. When parses the flat file, this will generate an XML element with this value.

**Field Attribute**: A value that you want to be in an XML attribute. When parses the flat file, this will generate an XML attribute with this value.

**Record**: A record that you need to descompose in the next step of the wizard in fields and attributes. When parses the flat file, this will generate an XML element, with the child elements that you define on the descomposition of the record.

**Repeating Record**: Similar to record, but will generate an XML element with MaxOccurs = unbounded. This is when you have a repeating structure in your flat file.

Comment: Really nice description, thank you! So just to be clear, lets say i wanted to create an xsd from a flat file. i would choose Record for the column headers and repeating record for the values related to each header?

Comment: Yes, a Record for the Header and a Repeating Record for the first row of the flat file, the other rows, you have to set to Ignore, because the structure is the same.

Comment: Ok Thank you, That made a lot os sense! :)